# Why do we need to reduce the mapped Boolean values to a single value in a function?

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

Why do we need to `reduce` the mapped Boolean Value to a single value at the end of the function?

The purpose of the function is to filter an array of objects (first argument) with the `key` `value` pairs from another object (second argument).

It should return another array of `object` with the objects from the first argument which matched both the `key` and `value` from the second argument.

For example if the first argument is `[{ first: "Romeo", last: "Montague" }, { first: "Mercutio", last: null }, { first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }]`

And the second is `{ last: "Capulet" }`

The function should return `[{ first: "Tybalt", last: "Capulet" }]`

This is the solution I stumbled upon and can't understand how the `map(`) and `reduce()` work here.

```
function whatIsInAName(collection, source) {
  var srcKeys = Object.keys(source);

  return collection.filter(function (obj) {
    return srcKeys
      .map(function(key) {
        return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
      })
      .reduce(function(a, b) {
        return a && b;
      });
  });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The `source` object potentially has multiple keys. The reduction to one boolean is there to attest that the filtered object contains and matches *all* properties of the `source` object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First the function creates an array of all keys it needs to look for in `srcKeys`, e.g. `['last']`. For the sake of illustrating this algorithm properly, let's assume you're looking for two keys, `source = { last: 'Capulet', first: 'Jon' }` → `['last', 'first']`.

Then it maps that array to an array of booleans, where each value signifies whether the item in `collection` has that key and whether its value is the same as in `source`. E.g.:

```
['last', 'first'] → [true, true]    // or
['last', 'first'] → [false, false]  // or
['last', 'first'] → [false, true]   // ...
```

It then reduces this array of booleans to a single boolean result, which will only be `true` if all items in the array are `true`:

```
[true, true]   → true
[false, false] → false
[false, true]  → false
```

---

FWIW, you could do that in one step using [`Array.prototype.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```
return collection.filter(obj => {
  return srcKeys.every(key => obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's start with this function which is used in the solution. It's a predicate which takes one of the keys from the object in `source` and returns a Boolean:

```
function(key) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
}
```

The slightly tricky thing is that it also references `obj`, which in context refers to one of the objects in `collection`. So you can think of it, at this point in the explanation, as a function of two variables really:

```
function(obj, key) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
}
```

So when is this true? That's easy: when `obj` has `key` as one of its keys, and for which the value equals that of `source` at the same key. In other words, it's checking that `obj` and `source` agree as far as the key `key` is concerned.

So what do we do with this function? We `map` it over the array `srcKeys` - which holds all the keys of `source`. So, remembering that this is with reference to a fixed object `obj`, we get an array of Booleans indicating whether each key of `source` is found, with the same value, in `obj`.

Then the `reduce` operation, which simply uses the `&&` operator, just checks whether *all* the values in this array of Booleans are true. So we see that this section of code:

```
return srcKeys
  .map(function(key) {
    return obj.hasOwnProperty(key) && obj[key] === source[key];
  })
  .reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a && b;
  });
```

returns a Boolean checking whether `obj` has all the keys specified in `source`, and agrees at the values.

The last step is now natural - `collection` is `filter`ed by this predicate, meaning the final result is an array consisting of those elements of `collection` which agree with `source` in all keys of `source`. Which is exactly what the desired behaviour was :)